# fetching data from model to controller to view not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in CI and I want to fetch data from DB using codeigniter in MVC way.
I can't seem to find any solution.

model: company.php | dbname: company

```
public function getAllcompany(){
    $query = $this->db->get('company');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        return array();
    }
```

view: branch.php

```
<?php
echo "<pre>", print_r($records), "</pre>";
?>
```

controller: home.php

```
public function getCompany(){
        $this->load->model('company','', TRUE);
        $data['records'] = $this->company->getAllcompany();

        $this->load->view('branch', $data);

    }
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, make user your `table` name is company and it have `rows`

Comment: I must agree with @ManojYadav. Code is not a problem. Look inside db. (make sure that you have select `development` environment on top of index.php file - you will see errors than)
You can also try use CI naming convention of templates And place branch.php in subfolder: `application/views/home/branch`. Than load it by `$this->load->view('home/branch', $data);`. This is only thing that dont looks fine.

Comment: hi @WebHQ I put this code in the top of my code. echo "<pre>", print_r($records), "</pre>"; and I got this error. 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: records

Filename: views/branch.php

Line Number: 2

Comment: @JaysonLacson please post class declarations from model `company.php` and from controller `home.php`

Comment: Helo Everyone! Thank you for your help, my mistake I have duplicate  the $this->load->view('branch', $data); in branch() function but now it works now. much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to change your model to :

```
public function getAllcompany(){

     $query = $this->db->get('company');

     return $query->result();

}
```

OR

```
    public function getAllcompany(){

       $query = $this->db->get('company');

       return $query->result_array();

    }
```